# Reference one schema from another in json-schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a json schema that defines some model and has references to common data types in separate schema.

```
{
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
      "address": {"$ref": "http://domain/commons.json#address"},
      "company": {"$ref": "http://domain/commons.json$company"},
   }
}
```

now this has problem that I have to put fully qualified ref in all places, whereas I'd like to specify commons.json schema url once, and then reference to it, like:

```
{
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
      "address": {"$ref": "#commons/address"},
      "company": {"$ref": "#commons/company"},
   }
   "commons": { "$ref": "http://domain/commons.json"
   }
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that won't work.  A `$ref` is a link to another document - which is not actually exactly the same as creating a clone of the remote document in-place.

However, if your first schema also lives on `http://domain/...` somewhere, then you could possible still use a relative path?